# Similarity vs congruence for symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that some symmetric matrix $S$ (everything here is over the field of real numbers) is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ via the invertible matrix $P$. We have: 
$P^{-1}DP=S.$

My question: must there exist an orthogonal matrix $O$ such that $O^{T}DO=S ?$

Note that it need not be the case in general that $P^{-1}=P^T.$ For instance, if $P:= \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $S$ is the identity, then we have $P^{-1}SP=P^{-1}IP=P$ but $P^T \neq P^{-1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, since $S$ is symmetric, then in particular it has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors. Hence if there exist two diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$ such that $S$ is similar to both of them, then $D_1$ and $D_2$ are identical, up to permutation of eigenvectors.

Hence, the answer to my question is yes! Indeed, suppose we have $P^{-1}DP=S$ for an arbitrary invertible matrix $P.$ We also know we must have $O^{T}D'O=S$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$ (by the spectral theorem).  And since $D'$ and $D$ are related simply by permutation of diagonal entries, there is certainly another orthogonal matrix $Q$ which takes $D$ to $D'.$

So $O^T Q^T D Q O=O^T D'O=S,$ which proves the claim since $QO$ is orthogonal.